# Ubuntu OS' parameters "locking" input audio for microphone

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headphones

My OS is Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS 64 bits (Gnome 3.36.8).
The microphone is on a headphone, G432 logitech, connected to my computer through its [USB audio adapter](https://www.logitech.com/assets/65644/3/g432.pdf).

Here you see what`alsamixer` displays:
[image]
The headphone's microphone is set ON.

Here you see what `pavucontrol` displays about audio inputs (tab called "périphériques d'entrées"):
[image]
The headphone is checked as default.

Here you see what Ubuntu parameters displays ("sortie" = output; "entrée" = input):
[image]
Clearly, I can't set any audio input, and I think that is the reason why my audio recorder don't manage to record my voice.

My research are fruitless until now. And note that audio output works perfectly fine, so that's not a matter of wrong device selected. Have you any idea how can I solve it ?